# Woocommerce - How to display a single product's specific attributes by way of list

Tags: php, html, css, woocommerce

I am trying to display a product's attributes , for each product, on its product page.
Currently it displays the attributes in the "Additional Information" tab.

I want it to be displayed on the short description \ before the add to cart button

I have searched the web for answers and found only this piece of code, which does display all the attributes, but I need only 1 type of attributes and its values to be displayed in a list

```
    function cw_woo_attribute(){
    global $product;
    $attributes = $product->get_attributes();
    if ( ! $attributes ) {
        return;
    }
    $display_result = '';
    foreach ( $attributes as $attribute ) {
        if ( $attribute->get_variation() ) {
            continue;
        }
        $name = $attribute->get_name();
        if ( $attribute->is_taxonomy() ) {
            $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $product->get_id(), $name, 'all' );
            $cwtax = $terms[0]->taxonomy;
            $cw_object_taxonomy = get_taxonomy($cwtax);
            if ( isset ($cw_object_taxonomy->labels->singular_name) ) {
                $tax_label = $cw_object_taxonomy->labels->singular_name;
            } elseif ( isset( $cw_object_taxonomy->label ) ) {
                $tax_label = $cw_object_taxonomy->label;
                if ( 0 === strpos( $tax_label, 'Product ' ) ) {
                    $tax_label = substr( $tax_label, 8 );
                }
            }
            $display_result .= $tax_label . ': ';
            $tax_terms = array();
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                $single_term = esc_html( $term->name );
                array_push( $tax_terms, $single_term );
            }
            $display_result .= implode(', ', $tax_terms) .  '<br />';
        } else {
            $display_result .= $name . ': ';
            $display_result .= esc_html( implode( ', ', $attribute->get_options() ) ) . '<br />';
        }
    }
    echo $display_result;
}
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'cw_woo_attribute', 25);

?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)